# Why are there frozen constants everywhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rack

We can easily find such style from lots of famous repositories, like rack, rails, etc.

[For example in rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/28e77c710ac2ddb35c436d78d72e28f28f964446/lib/rack.rb):

```
PATH_INFO      = 'PATH_INFO'.freeze
REQUEST_METHOD = 'REQUEST_METHOD'.freeze
SCRIPT_NAME    = 'SCRIPT_NAME'.freeze
QUERY_STRING   = 'QUERY_STRING'.freeze
CACHE_CONTROL  = 'Cache-Control'.freeze
CONTENT_LENGTH = 'Content-Length'.freeze
CONTENT_TYPE   = 'Content-Type'.freeze
```

[Another examle in rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=freeze):

```
HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE = 'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'.freeze
HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH     = 'HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'.freeze
HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH     = 'HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'.freeze
```

I wonder why these constant strings are frozen. Since they are all constants, there should be only one instance. Of course we can put `"foo".freeze` somewhere to reference the same singleton instance, however people usually write literal variable name like `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE`instead.

So in my opinion, it doesn't make any difference in spite of using `#freeze`, so why do people freeze constants?

Comment: To stop people mutating them by accident?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is correct that Ruby prints a warning when you re-assign a value to an already initialized constant:

```
FOO = 'foo'
FOO = 'bar'
# :2: warning: already initialized constant FOO
# :1: warning: previous definition of FOO was here
FOO
#=> "bar"
```

But there is no protection from changing parts of the value of the constant. Example without `freeze`:

```
FOO = 'foo'
FOO[1] = '-'
FOO
#=> "f-o"
```

But `freeze` allows protecting the value of the constants from being changed. Example with `freeze`:

```
FOO = 'foo'.freeze
FOO[1] = '-'
#=> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's ridiculous that I remember the magic effect of `String#freeze`, but forget the original intention of `#freeze`...Orz

Comment: I believe the main reason in Rack and Rails is performance related. See [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/unraveling-string-key-performance-ruby-2-2/) from Richard Schneeman regarding optimizations from using `String#freeze`

Answer (score 8):

normally Rubyist freeze string literals to make execution faster. If there is some function call for example like below in some controller, every request will call that function.

```
log("debug")
```

what happens is ruby defines a new garbage string object every time. Object allocation is not free. it consumes memory and CPU. Garbage will be there till GC collects them.

but if literals are frozen

```
log("debug".freeze)
```

ruby allocates once and caches it for later use. Also, the string object will be immutable and safe for use in the multithreaded environment.

> From ruby 3.0 ruby is gonna freeze every string, - according to Matz.

---

**update:**

If you add the following comment in the beginning of ruby file then every string literal in the entire file will be immutable. This is pretty helpful when you are trying to optimize your app for the muti-threaded environment.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

or you can even start your Ruby process with `--enable-frozen-string-literal` switch.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation why you see this consistent freezing of constants in popular projects is that they use [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), a code analyzer.

It's a standard Rubocop [rule](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/MutableConstant) that constants shouldn't be mutable, for the reasons mentioned above by @spickermann.